# How can I use the MSVC compiler from Github Actions?

Tags: c++, github, visual-c++, github-actions

I want to have a pipeline which compiles my code with MSVC++ `cl` compiler, since my native project is done in Visual Studio. How can I import these tools, and on which Operating Systems are they available on?

Comment: All image information can be found in https://github.com/actions/virtual-environments if you use the managed hosts by GitHub. Compare your local VS workloads to images such as Windows Server 2019 https://github.com/actions/virtual-environments/blob/main/images/win/Windows2019-Readme.md and you can see if the necessary bits are installed already.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found a GitHub repo that allows you to use MSVC++ tools. Just add this before your job:
`- uses: ilammy/msvc-dev-cmd@v1`
Here's my workflow file for reference:
https://github.com/satanic-santa/spark/blob/master/.github/workflows/compile.yml

Answer (score 5):

Alternatively, if you don't want to use an external GitHub Action (e.g. because of your company's security policy), you can run `VsDevCmd.bat` manually:

```yaml
- name: Compile Visual Studio project with MSBuild
  shell: cmd 
  run: ${{ '"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\Common7\Tools\VsDevCmd.bat" && msbuild' }}
  working-directory: path/to/your/project
```

The command after `&&` (`msbuild`) runs as if it was executed inside the "Developer Command Prompt for Visual Studio 2022".
Note that this will work only on Windows, AFAIK you can't use the Microsoft's C++ compiler on other operating systems.

This solution is bound to the installation location of Visual Studio 2022 in the GitHub runner image `windows-2022`, see the [Readme](https://github.com/actions/runner-images/blob/main/images/win/Windows2022-Readme.md#visual-studio-enterprise-2022).
Therefore, you might need to update the path to `VsDevCmd.bat` if you use another image, such as `windows-2019`, a custom image, or some other image with the next version of Visual Studio in the future.